# How can I fix this type X is not assignable to type Y error in typescript?

Tags: typescript, express

In my express app I have the following middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  let _end = res.end;
  res.end = function end(chunk, encoding) {
    ...
    return _end.call(res, chunk, encoding);
  };
  next();
});
```

This return the following typescript error:

> error TS2322: Type '(chunk: any, encoding: any) => any' is not
>   assignable to type '{ (): void; (buffer: Buffer, cb?: Function): void;
>   (str: string, cb?: Function): void; (str: stri...'.

in `@types/node/index.d.ts` `end` method is described like this:

```
end(): void;
end(buffer: Buffer, cb?: Function): void;
end(str: string, cb?: Function): void;
end(str: string, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void;
end(data?: any, encoding?: string): void;
```

What would be the correct type to fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to override Response.end in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243333/correct-way-to-override-response-end-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you intend to use one of the available overloads: `end(data?: any, encoding?: string): void;`
If that is the case, you just need to make your function signature explicitly compatible. Instead of

```
// ...
res.end = function end(chunk, encoding) {
// ...
```

use

```
// ...
res.end = function end(chunk?:any, encoding?:string) {
// ...
```

And make sure that you correctly handle corner cases, e.g. where arguments are not passed at all.

Comment: Well, `chunk?:any, encoding?:any` did the trick. `chunk?:any, encoding?:string` was still returning an error...

Comment: Remembering to avoid using `any` in common cases, use `unknown` instead to ensure type safety or create a new type to your data.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any