# Correct way to override Response.end in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, express

I'm writing a replacement for express-session in Typescript (because I want to use JWT tokens rather than cookies).

I've hit a snag when it comes to overriding Response.end (in order to save the session after the request has been handled).

The signature appears to be as follows:

```
end(cb?: Function): void;
end(chunk: any, cb?: Function): void;
end(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void;
```

So the following works:

```
const end: {
                (cb?: Function): void;
                (chunk: any, cb?: Function): void;
                (chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void; 
            } = res.end;
```

However, I am unsure how to provide a replacement for res.end which matches these call signatures.

express-session appears to override like this:

```
res.end = function end(chunk, encoding) {
```

However, when I try to provide a replacement:

```
res.end = function(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function)
{

}
```

The compiler moans:

```
error TS2322: Type '(chunk: any, encoding?: string | undefined, cb?: Function | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: Function | undefined): void; (chunk: any, cb?: Function | undefined): void; (chunk: any, ...'.
  Types of parameters 'encoding' and 'cb' are incompatible.
    Type 'Function | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
        Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

The first definition does work fine, however:

```
res.end = function(cb?: Function): void
{

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**: I've found that I can work around this issue by casting the Response object to *any*:

```
(<any>res).end = function(chunk: any, encoding?: string): void
{
    end.call(res, chunk, encoding);
};
```

However, my original question still stands: is there a way to do this in a typed way?

Comment: I am surprised the signature you provided to be valid, shouldn't it be : ```(cb?: Function): void; | (chunk: any, cb?: Function): void; | (chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void;```

Comment: Well, actually I just copied the syntax I'm using directly from the error output from the Typescript compiler.  It works, I guess it's just another way of representing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument can be an encoding (string) or a callback (Function).  Your provided method does not consider that scenario.  Also, there is no guarantee the first argument will be there.  You need to do:

```
res.end = function(chunk?: any, encodingOrCb?: string | Function, cb?: Function): void {

}
```